# Running RViz inside a docker container on macOS Sonoma

Tags: ros, rviz, docker, macos, opengl

I am trying to run RViz inside a docker container created from arm64v8/ros:noetic image

Background info

- MacBook Air M2
- MacOS Sonoma 14.0
- Docker Desktop Version 4.24.2 (124339)
- XQuartz 2.8.5 (xorg-server 21.1.6)

The script that I use to start the container

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
xhost +
name="rosarm"
if [ -n "$(docker ps -aq -f name=$name)" ]; then
    if [ "$(docker ps -aq -f status=exited -f name=$name)" ]; then
        echo "Container $name is exited. Starting..."
        docker container start $name
    fi
    echo "Attaching to the container $name..."
    docker exec -it $name bash
else
    echo "Could not found the container $name. Running a new one..."
    docker run -it \
    -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0 \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    -v $(pwd)/app:/app/ \
    --privileged \
    --name $name \
    arm64v8/ros:noetic \
    bash
fi
```

Installed ros-noetic-rviz with

```bash
apt update
apt install -y ros-noetic-rviz
```

At this point running rviz

```bash
rosrun rviz rviz
```

yields the following outputs

```bash
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

To get rid of this errors I have installed mesa packages

```bash
apt install -y mesa-utils libgl1-mesa-glx
```

and exported the following variable

```bash
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
```

With this changes the libGL error lines are not printed anymore but still segmentation fault happens

Running rviz with gdb

```
gdb) run
Starting program: /opt/ros/noetic/bin/rviz 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0xffffef515e80 (LWP 4266)]
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
[ INFO] [1698240655.353090509]: rviz version 1.14.20
[ INFO] [1698240655.353127800]: compiled against Qt version 5.12.8
[ INFO] [1698240655.353135592]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
[New Thread 0xffffee4c7e80 (LWP 4268)]
[New Thread 0xffffedcc6e80 (LWP 4269)]
[New Thread 0xffffed4c5e80 (LWP 4270)]
[New Thread 0xffffeccc4e80 (LWP 4271)]
[ INFO] [1698240655.360729842]: Forcing OpenGl version 0.
[New Thread 0xffffd7ffee80 (LWP 4272)]
[Detaching after fork from child process 4273]

Thread 1 "rviz" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

and checking the stack trace with bt

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000ffffd6c78130 in ?? () from /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.9.0/RenderSystem_GL.so.1.9.0
#2  0x0000ffffd6c52974 in Ogre::GLStateCacheManager::switchContext(long) () from /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.9.0/RenderSystem_GL.so.1.9.0
#3  0x0000ffffd6c45338 in Ogre::GLRenderSystem::initialiseContext(Ogre::RenderWindow*) () from /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.9.0/RenderSystem_GL.so.1.9.0
#4  0x0000ffffd6c4d4ec in Ogre::GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Ogre::STLAllocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy<(Ogre::MemoryCategory)0> > > const*) () from /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.9.0/RenderSystem_GL.so.1.9.0
#5  0x0000fffff6ab7d38 in Ogre::Root::createRenderWindow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Ogre::STLAllocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy<(Ogre::MemoryCategory)0> > > const*) () from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.9.0
#6  0x0000fffff7ec4598 in rviz::RenderSystem::tryMakeRenderWindow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Ogre::STLAllocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy<(Ogre::MemoryCategory)0> > > const*, int) () from /opt/ros/noetic/lib/librviz.so
#7  0x0000fffff7ec5b14 in rviz::RenderSystem::makeRenderWindow(unsigned long, unsigned int, unsigned int, double) () from /opt/ros/noetic/lib/librviz.so
#8  0x0000fffff7ec7648 in rviz::RenderSystem::RenderSystem() () from /opt/ros/noetic/lib/librviz.so
#9  0x0000fffff7ec77f4 in rviz::RenderSystem::get() () from /opt/ros/noetic/lib/librviz.so
#10 0x0000fffff7ec38a0 in rviz::QtOgreRenderWindow::QtOgreRenderWindow(QWidget*) () from /opt/ros/noetic/lib/librviz.so
#11 0x0000fffff7ee9d20 in rviz::RenderPanel::RenderPanel(QWidget*) () from /opt/ros/noetic/lib/librviz.so
#12 0x0000fffff7f33ee0 in rviz::VisualizationFrame::initialize(QString const&) () from /opt/ros/noetic/lib/librviz.so
#13 0x0000fffff7f3de50 in rviz::VisualizerApp::init(int, char**) () from /opt/ros/noetic/lib/librviz.so
#14 0x0000aaaaaaaa3804 in main ()
(gdb)
```

The output of the ldconfig

```bash
root@43d58e80078f:/# ldconfig -p | grep -i gl.so
    libwayland-egl.so.1 (libc6,AArch64) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (libc6,AArch64) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5
    libOpenGL.so.0 (libc6,AArch64) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so.0
    libOpenGL.so (libc6,AArch64) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
    libGL.so.1 (libc6,AArch64) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
    libEGL.so.1 (libc6,AArch64) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1
    libEGL.so (libc6,AArch64) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
```

Could you help me about getting this working?

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading your XQuartz's version.
It worked for me(few times) then it started crashing again